# How to copy modifiers with attribute values from active object to selected objects with python scripting?

Tags: python

Is there a better way to ***copy a modifier with all attributes*** from *active object* to *selected object* through python scripting other than adding a modifier to selected and copy attributes one by one (with dictionary for example) from active?

The **problem** is **some *attributes are read-only*** (even if it makes no sense - like for example *subdivision* algorithm in *Subsurf* modifier) and i don't know how to set them through python script.
So i can't copy that *subdivision* algorithm value from one to another through scripting with method setting a value for an attribute:

```
bpy.data.objects[object_name].modifiers[modifier_name].attribute_name = attribute_value
```

So to reiterate my question: is there any other way to add a modifier to an object that would allow setting up values for **all** attributes?

Comment: You could copy the object (incl. modifiers) and let a script set all non-modifier related properties to the target object's properties, but it's basically the same as copying modifier attributes...

Comment: You may want to investigate the source of the Copy Attributes add-on. It provides the functionality of copying modifiers. At the very least, you can see how it's done there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

A modifier can only be inserted through [`modifiers.new`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new), so its properties do need to be copied individually. The problem here is in checking *which properties* can be copied. (e.g., *Subsurf* modifier's [`subdivision_type`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.SubsurfModifier.html#bpy.types.SubsurfModifier.subdivision_type) property is actually *not* readonly as you claimed, but we'd need to test it manually or check the [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.SubsurfModifier.html#bpy.types.SubsurfModifier.subdivision_type) to find out.)

The whole "check writability then copy" procedure can be done more efficiently, though. For example, see this function:

```
import bpy

def main():
    active_object = bpy.context.object
    selected_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects
                        if o != active_object and o.type == active_object.type]

    for obj in selected_objects:
        for mSrc in active_object.modifiers:
            mDst = obj.modifiers.get(mSrc.name, None)
            if not mDst:
                mDst = obj.modifiers.new(mSrc.name, mSrc.type)

            # collect names of writable properties
            properties = [p.identifier for p in mSrc.bl_rna.properties
                          if not p.is_readonly]

            # copy those properties
            for prop in properties:
                setattr(mDst, prop, getattr(mSrc, prop))

main()
```

It copies all modifiers from active object, to every other selected objects of similar type. What modifier properties to copy is determined by checking [`is_readonly`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Property.html#bpy.types.Property.is_readonly) attribute of all items in the modifier's `bl_rna.properties`. This way, we can ensure that only writable properties get copied.

In the API Reference, some readonly attributes like *Dynamic Paint*'s [`brush_settings`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.DynamicPaintModifier.html#bpy.types.DynamicPaintModifier.brush_settings) have no other method of access, so they can be set only through the UI.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. For some reason i still can't write some attributes with my code (i've simply used try/except to avoid read-only attributes, so there must be other reason that prevented some of the attributes from updating), but your code works without a problem. Thank you.

Comment: Truly awesome answer!

Comment: great answer!!!!

Answer (score 6):

A simpler method than Adhi's is to use `make_links_data`

Say you make two cubes. You apply modifiers to the first one and want to copy them to the second one. Then your code should look something like this:

```
import bpy

mod_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]           # cube with mods
modable_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube.001"]   # cube without mods

mod_obj.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = mod_obj
modable_obj.select = True

bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='MODIFIERS')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Adhi's answer.

Maybe below can be useful for someone in the future. Can be more Pythonic and beautiful, but I think below should collect all the Modifier Props from ob for obtarget, providing obtarget already has all the Modifiers being generated based on ob.

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
obtarget = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']

mod_props = []

for mod in ob.modifiers:
    properties = []
    for prop in mod.bl_rna.properties:
        if not prop.is_readonly:
            properties.append(prop.identifier)
    mod_props.append([mod, properties])

for stuff in mod_props:
    for prop in stuff[1]:
        setattr(obtarget.modifiers[stuff[0].name], prop, getattr(stuff[0], prop))
```

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to refactor Adhi's answer to a class for easier usage:

```py
from typing import Any, NamedTuple

import bpy


class ModifierSpec(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    type: str
    properties: dict[str, Any]

    @classmethod
    def from_modifier(cls, modifier):
        spec = cls(modifier.name, modifier.type, {})

        for prop in modifier.bl_rna.properties:
            if prop.is_readonly:
                continue

            name = prop.identifier
            spec.properties[name] = getattr(modifier, name)

        return spec

    def add_to_object(self, obj):
        new_modifier = obj.modifiers.get(self.name, None)
        if new_modifier is None:
            new_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(self.name, self.type)

        for name, prop in self.properties.items():
            setattr(new_modifier, name, prop)


# collect modifiers from object
modifier_specs: list[ModifierSpec] = []
for old_modifier in source_obj.modifiers:
    modifier_specs.append(ModifierSpec.from_modifier(old_modifier))

# add modifiers from spec
for spec in modifier_specs:
    spec.add_to_object(dest_obj)
```

Comment: Looks nice and tidy. You might want to add a guard clause somewhere if the user tries to copy modifiers to an object that doesn't support it like an empty object, since `new_modifier` will then be `None` and the subsequent lines will throw an error. Thank you for sharing !

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which uses an [operator override](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248274/a-comprehensive-list-of-operator-overrides) of [object.modifier_copy_to_selected](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected) and doesn't require you to select objects.

```
import bpy

source = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
target = bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"]
modifier_name = "Solidify"

with bpy.context.temp_override(object=source, selected_objects=(source, target)):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_copy_to_selected(modifier=modifier_name)
```