# Is it possible to link a modifier for only one Render Layer?

Tags: modifiers, render-layers

I have a scene in which I want to render some of the same objects in two separate *Render Layers*, with different modifiers in each *Render Layer*. I know how to link modifiers using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *> Modifiers*, all I want to know if there is a feature, add-on, or the possibility of adding a feature, like the change all *Materials* option, just for modifiers.

In very simple terms, how can you animate the linking of Modifiers? (change the link parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a code that keeps a specific group of objects related to another object modifiers this is how it works :

- add the selected objects to a group named 'linked objects'
- rename the active object  'source object'
- whenever the function is called it copies the modifiers parameters from the 'source object' to the rest objects in the group and if the modifier is not present it creates a new one
- the function is appended to the `scene_update_pre()` handler to be called automatically

**Note :**
 - before you run the script make sure to select your objects and the active object is going to be the source object thus it will be renamed ( you can make a dummy object as the source to keep the names) 
 - you can add/remove other objects later to/from the group because the update is related to the group not specific objects

```
import bpy

bpy.context.active_object.name = 'source_object'
linked_objects = bpy.data.groups.new('Linked_objects')
selected_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects 
                            if obj.type == bpy.context.active_object.type]
for obj in selected_objects:        
      linked_objects.objects.link(obj)


def link_modifiers(context):

    linked_objects = bpy.data.groups['Linked_objects'].objects
    source_object = bpy.context.scene.objects['source_object']

    for obj in linked_objects:
        for mSrc in source_object.modifiers:
            mDst = obj.modifiers.get(mSrc.name, None)
            if not mDst:
                mDst = obj.modifiers.new(mSrc.name, mSrc.type)

            # collect names of writeable properties
            properties = [p.identifier for p in mSrc.bl_rna.properties
                          if not p.is_readonly]

            # copy those properties
            for prop in properties:
                setattr(mDst, prop, getattr(mSrc, prop))

bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(link_modifiers)
```

the code for copying the modifiers is from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4883/5113) by [Adhi](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/185/adhi) so thanks Adhi

the code needs more tweaking especially the handler choice I'm new to this so any advice would be appreciated

**Animation Render test** with two modifiers with drivers applied only to the source object "the orange cube":
[render result](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/84069)

Comment: Looks like this has a lot of potential! How does it respond to render layer rendering during i.e. rendering an animation?

Comment: I'm not sure yet :) , but i think that the 'scene_update_pre' get called alot so it will be always updated ' i guess'

Comment: Let me know of any updates then, would be glad to find a solution that definitely works.

Comment: Very cool! There appears to be some delay though in the link, I saw the orange one go first, then a frame or two later the others would change. Is that the case?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise yes i've noticed that ,so i have to ask about the force update the script with every frame change ? do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't, not a huge scripting guy myself

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise would this question be considered unfit to blender-exchange ?

Comment: Nope, go ahead and ask (check for duplicates first of course)