# What context does make_links_data need?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, linked-data

I can't get `bpy.ops.make_links_data` to work with context overrides. When I select objects manually, it works fine, but the following doesn't:

```
bpy.ops.object.make_links_data({
    "active_object": source, 
    "object": source, 
    "selected_objects": [source, target]}, 
type='MODIFIERS')
```

I would expect the objects given `"selected_objects"` to have the same modifiers as the object in `"active_object"` or the one in `"object"`. This does not seem to happen. (I can't see anything happening at all.)

When I manually link the modifiers (which works), the line

```
bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='MODIFIERS')
```

appears in the scripting panel.

(This is in Blender 2.8.)

Comment: Could you provide more details what you are trying to do and what result is expected?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've added some.

Comment: I would recommend to use this approach [https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4883/50172](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4883/50172) instead of using of operator. Also I have tested the proposed method on my side and it works

Answer (score 1):

You have to [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) like this:

```
import bpy

area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

override = {
    'window': bpy.context.window,
    'screen': bpy.context.window.screen,
    'area': areas[0],
    'region': [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
}

bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(override, type='MODIFIERS')
```

But it is best to avoid the `bpy.ops` which is dependent on context, and directly manipulate the data. You can easily create the same function which is independent of context like so:

```
import bpy

def link_modifiers(active_object, selected_objects, clear_existing_modifiers=True):
    if len(selected_objects) <= 1:
        return

    for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if o is active_object:
            continue

        if clear_existing_modifiers:
            o.modifiers.clear()

        for m in active_object.modifiers:
            o.modifiers.new(m.name, m.type)

link_modifiers(bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active, bpy.context.selected_objects, True)
```